# Why does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kp (1-p)^{(k-1)} p$ converge to 1 for all probabilities p?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm playing a game where I can pay $\$p$ to succeed with probability $p$. I can choose the value of $p$, and I want to play repeatedly until exactly one success. What should I choose?

Assume I achieve my first success after $k$ attempts. Then I paid a total of $kp$. I must have failed $k-1$ times and succeeded once, so the probability of this happening is $(1-p)^{(k-1)} p^1$.

Summing over all $k$, my expected total cost is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kp (1-p)^{(k-1)} p
$$

I then [tried this formula in WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20kp%20*%20%281-p%29%5E%28k-1%29%28p%29%20from%201%20to%20infinity%20where%20p%20%3D%200.5) with various choices of $p \in (0,1)$ and found that they all converge to 1. This is also the cost if I choose $p=1$ for a guaranteed immediate success.

I'm interested in understanding why this happens for all $p$, from both intuitive and algebraic perspectives.

Answer (score 2):

From the geometric series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)^k = \frac{1}{p}$$
(valid for $|1-p|<1$, thus in particular for $0 < p < 1$),
differentiate with respect to $p$ to get
$$ -\sum_{k=1}^\infty k (1-p)^{k-1} = - \frac{1}{p^2}$$
and then multiply by $-p^2$.

Of course it's not true for $p=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by algebraic perspective you mean to calculate this series? It is of the form $p^2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}$. Now as to compute $\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$ note it is the same as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}x^k$. Now, it is a power series, so we can swap differential operator with sum if we work inside radius of convergence (in your example works, since $p \in (0,1)$ means $x = (1-p) \in (0,1)$ ). So we get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1} = \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. By that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1} = \frac{1}{p^2}$, so your whole result is $1$.

Now from the probabilistic point of view, you're playing until first success, so let's say  $\tau = \inf \{ k \ge 1 : X_k = 1 \}$, where $X_1,X_2,...$ are independent outcomes of your game $(1 $ when success, $0$ otherwise $)$. You're interested in $\mathbb E[p\tau]$ (since $\tau$ is just the (random!) number of the first success and you need to multiply number of trials by $p$). But $\mathbb E[\tau] = \frac{1}{p}$ (since $\tau$ follows geometric distrubution with parameter $p$), so your whole cost - $\mathbb E[p \tau] = 1$ no matter what $ p \in (0,1)$ you've chosen.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is meant by $\tau = \inf \{ k \ge 1 : X_k = 1 \}$ ? I'm not familiar with this notation. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: $\tau(\omega) = \inf\{ k \ge 1 : X_k(\omega) = 1 \}$. It is the number of the game with first success, written more formally